# Containerd default ownership

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, samba, ownership

After installation of dperson/samba Docker container, I set up a share for the /opt folder to modify some configurations of other container directly via smb protocol (bad idea!).

I made the mistake of having permissions set by SAMBA, now I have noticed that the /opt/containerd folder has changed ownership in "systemd-journal", and now I don't remember if the previous property was the "root" or "docker" user .

Could you please tell me what is the default property on this folder?

P.S. Sorry for my english, I'm Italian :-)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> ll -d /opt/containerd/
drwx--x--x 4 root root 4096 Mar 30 22:26 /opt/containerd//
```

On a machine on which I installed docker a couple of days ago... Note the specific flags (same flags on `/opt/containerd/bin` and `/opt/containerd/lib`).